# SQL0206N "SQLSTATE" is not valid in the context where it is used. SQLSTATE=42703

Tags: cursor, db2

the following code when executed using  db2 -td@ -f./sql/update_product.sql
gives error as:
SQL0206N  "SQLSTATE" is not valid in the context where it is used.  LINE
NUMBER=53.  SQLSTATE=42703

Please help...

```
  SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
  @
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPLOADPRODUCTATTRIBUTES
  BEGIN 
  DECLARE   v_eisidentifier VARCHAR(100);
  DECLARE   v_categoryGuid DECIMAL(19,0); 
  DECLARE   v_localeGuid DECIMAL(19,0);
  DECLARE   v_realmGuid DECIMAL(19,0);
  DECLARE   v_catchingPhrase VARCHAR(120) ;
  DECLARE   v_genericName VARCHAR(80);
  DECLARE   v_ingredients VARCHAR(900);
  DECLARE   v_quantity VARCHAR (60);
  DECLARE   v_dose VARCHAR(40);
  DECLARE   v_nutritionFacts VARCHAR (900);
  DECLARE   v_productDescription VARCHAR(900);
  DECLARE   v_recommendedFor VARCHAR(200);
  DECLARE   v_promotionMessage VARCHAR(200);
  DECLARE   v_message VARCHAR (4500);
  DECLARE   v_proudctGuid DECIMAL(19,0);
  DECLARE   C1 CURSOR FOR
SELECT 
        EISIDENTIFIER,
        CATEGORY_GUID,
        LOCALEGUID,
        REALMGUID,
        CATCHING_PHRASE,
        GENERIC_NAME,
        INGREDIENTS,
        QUANTITY,
        DOSE,
        NUTIRITION_FACTS,
        PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION,
        RECOMMENDED_FOR,
        PROMOTION_MESSAGE,
        MESSAGE
    FROM 
        TEMP_UPLOAD_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES;

        OPEN C1;
        FETCH C1 into v_eisidentifier,  
                      v_categoryGuid, 
                      v_localeGuid,
                      v_realmGuid,
                      v_catchingPhrase,
                      v_genericName,
                      v_ingredients,
                      v_quantity,
                      v_dose,
                      v_nutritionFacts,
                      v_productDescription,
                      v_recommendedFor,
                      v_promotionMessage,
                      v_message
        ;
        WHILE (SQLSTATE = '00000') 
        DO
            IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PRD_PRODUCT WHERE EISIDENTIFIER = v_eisidentifier)
            THEN
                SELECT GUID INTO v_productGuid FROM PRD_PRODUCT WHERE EISIDENTIFIER = v_eisidentifier;

                UPDATE PRD_PRODUCT_L10N
                SET CATEGORY_GUID = v_categoryGuid,
                    REALMGUID = v_realmGuid,
                    CATCHING_PHRASE =v_catchingPhrase,
                    GENERIC_NAME =v_genericName,
                    INGREDIENTS =v_ingredients,
                    QUANTITY=v_quantity,
                    DOSE=v_dose,
                    NUTIRITION_FACTS=v_nutritionFacts,
                    PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION=v_productDescription,
                    RECOMMENDED_FOR=v_recommendedFor,
                    PROMOTION_MESSAGE=v_promotionMessage,
                    MESSAGE=v_message
                WHERE PRODUCTGUID =v_proudctGuid and LOCALGUID =v_categoryGuid;

                IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PRD_PRODUCT_CATEGORY WHERE CATEGORY_GUID=v_categoryGuid AND PRODUCT_GUID=v_productGuid)
                THEN
                    INSERT INTO PRD_PRODUCT_CATEGORY (CATEGORY_GUID, PRODUCT_GUID) VALUES (v_categoryGuid,v_productGuid);
                ELSE 
                    -- do nothing
                END IF;
            ELSE 
                --  INSERT INTO --- should not be the case....
            END IF;


            FETCH C1 into v_productGuid,    
                      v_categoryGuid, 
                      v_localeGuid,
                      v_realmGuid,
                      v_catchingPhrase,
                      v_genericName,
                      v_ingredients,
                      v_quantity,
                      v_dose,
                      v_nutritionFacts,
                      v_productDescription,
                      v_recommendedFor,
                      v_promotionMessage,
                      v_message
            ;
        END WHILE;
    CLOSE c1;           
  END 
  @
```

Answer (score 3):

The stored procedure is telling you that you did not declare the `SQLSTATE` variable.
Even though SQLSTATE is a special variable, whose value is implicitly maintained by the database (the stored procedure interpreter or compiler), you still need to declare it when you want to use it:

```
DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR(5);
```

By the way, the same goes for the SQLCODE variable:

```
DECLARE SQLCODE INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
```

[Here's the documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSEPGG_9.1.0/com.ibm.db2.udb.apdv.sql.doc/doc/c0009028.htm) for an older version, but it should still apply.

**Important**: The value of SQLSTATE applies (only) to the immediately preceding statement.
If you use a handler to handle warnings and exceptions, and you want to use the SQLSTATE value in the handler, and your handler consists of more than one statement, you need to save the SQLSTATE value before doing anything else.

The WHILE loop in your example works only as long as the last statement in the loop body is the one that determines the SQLSTATE value. An alternative is to use a dedicated boolean `done`, and, depending on your logic, a `continue handler for not found` that sets it to TRUE.

Comment: Good find.  This does answer the question (more directly than what I wrote), although personally I think this is still likely a poor way to do what the OP is attempting.  At minimum, `SQLSTATE`/`SQLCODE` values may indicate warnings that you don't actually care about, so the `00000` values usually shouldn't be strictly coded against.

Comment: I agree on all counts. Whether the set or the iteration approach is better, depends on many aspects though, skill, readability, and performance being some of them.

Answer (score 0):

As near as I'm able to tell, SQLSTATE doesn't exist in the format you're thinking of; and at the minimum, you can't use it to control your loop execution (here) anyways.  Instead, you need to use things called `HANDLER`s (`CONTINUE` and `EXCEPTION`, at minimum) - `SQLSTATE` is available *outside* the **entire** procedure (...pretty much).

Besides which, you're using a loop for no discernable benefit - the entire procedure can be re-written to a couple of standard `INSERT`s.  You'll need to finish off the procedure, but your statements amount to:

```
UPDATE Prd_Product_L10N as a
SET (category_guid, realmGuid, catching_phrase, 
     generic_name, ingredients, quantity, dose, 
     nutrition_facts, product_description, recommended_for, 
     promotion_message, message) = 
               (SELECT b.category_guid, b.realmGuid, b.catching_phrase, 
                       b.generic_name, b.ingredients, b.quantity, b.dose, 
                       b.nutrition_facts, b.product_description, b.recommended_for, 
                       b.promotion_message, b.message
                 FROM Temp_Upload_Product_Attributes as b
                 JOIN Prd_Product as c
                 ON c.eisIdentifier = b.eisIdentifier
                 AND c.guid = a.productGuid
                 WHERE b.category_guid = a.localGuid)

WHERE EXISTS (SELECT '1' 
              FROM Temp_Upload_Product_Attributes as b
              JOIN Prd_Product as c
              ON c.eisIdentifier = b.eisIdentifier
              AND c.guid = a.productGuid
              WHERE b.category_Guid = a.localGuid);

INSERT INTO Prd_Product_Category (category_guid, product_guid)
SELECT a.localGuid, a.productGuid
FROM Prd_Product_L10N as a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT '1'
                  FROM Prd_Product_Category as b
                  WHERE b.category_guid = a.localGuid
                  AND b.product_guid = a.productGuid);
```

Please note that, because of the way the optimizer works, these are *likely* to be **much** faster (how much, or even if, can't be answered without running the analyzer).  Lets face it: looping and using cursors is **not** how SQL is really meant to be used - SQL was created for doing 'Set' work, so write statements in that paradigm.  There *are* occasions where loops are necessary, but this isn't one of them.